# Integrations under different coordinate systems

Tags: integration

I asked Mathematica to do a very simple integration exercise for me. I tried on two different approaches, one on Cartesian and the other on Polar Coordinates, however, it gives me two different results. What is the mistakes I made?
[image]

The Mathematica's Codes I used are as follows:

```
NIntegrate[
```

x^2 y^2 (3 - 2 x^2 - y^2)^2 Sqrt[1 + 16 x^2 + 4 y^2], {x, -Sqrt[3/2],
   Sqrt[3/2]}, {y, -Sqrt[3 - 2 x^2], Sqrt[3 - 2 x^2]}]

```
NIntegrate[
```

r^5 Cos[t]^2 Sin[
   t]^2 (3 - 2 r^2 Cos[t]^2 - 
    r^2 Sin[t]^2)^2 [Sqrt](1 + 16 r^2 Cos[t]^2 + 4 r^2 Sin[t]^2), {t,
   0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, Sqrt[3 Cos[t]^2/2 + 3 Sin[t]^2]}]

---

Shifrin, Sorry, I misused the term *Polar System* in my question, What I did in the second approach actually was a transformation from a ellipse to a circle. I tried again and keep on using the Cartesian coord., but still the result doesn't match with the first approach. What is wrong in my calculations?

[image]

```
NIntegrate[
```

u^2 v^2 (3 - u^2 - v^2)^2 Sqrt[
   1 + 4 u^2 + 4 v^2]/(2 Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqUWQ.jpg)), {v, -Sqrt[3], Sqrt[
  3]}, {u, -Sqrt[3 - v^2], Sqrt[3 - v^2]}]

Comment: when you substitute $x = \sqrt {\frac {3}{2}} r \cos\theta ,  y = \sqrt {3} r \sin\theta$, you drop the coefficients.  Also the limits of $r$ should be $0$ to $1.$

Comment: @DougM: The OP may not know about general changes of variables, Jacobians, etc. But we gave the same advice in the event that one has that technique available.

Answer (score 2):

It's too bad you haven't learned a more general change of variables, like using $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$. Then you'll just have $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$ and $0\le r\le\sqrt3$.

Your mistake, however, is in the $r$ ($\rho$) limit of your polar coordinate integral. The equation of the bounding ellipse is $2x^2+y^2=3$, so this becomes $\rho^2(2\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=3$, and so you should have
$$0\le\rho\le\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}}.$$
(Ugh!) When you write the equations $x=\sqrt{\frac32}\cos\theta$, $y=\sqrt3\sin\theta$ parametrizing the ellipse, you are wrong; to use this parametrization, $\theta$ will *not* be the polar coordinate $\theta$. (Draw a picture to see why.)